# Atom Editor Django model autocomplete db model field types

Tags: django, autocomplete, models, atom-editor

I like using Atom for Django projects and most of the autocomplete is working as well as linting but ....

I would thing the the type of the model fields could be autocompleted for example:

```
name = models.***CharField***(max_length=256)
    age = models.***PositiveIntegerField***()
    school = models.***ForeignKey***(School, related_name='students')
```

is there a plugin that autocompletes these db filed types?

Comment: have you looked at https://atom.io/packages/django-atom and https://atom.io/packages/atom-django?

Comment: I added atom-django but not django-atom and I see in the doc page that it has some of what I wanted - Thanks. Now I am wrestling a bit with pep8 linter messages - some I wan to disable. I found the config file but I think my syntax for the lines  added is not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working within a virtuaenv, in atom navigate to Packages > Virtualenv and select the name of the virtualenv project you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

open terminal in your base directory activate your virtualenv then type `atom .`

enjoy !